# html5 localstorage storage and access

Tags: html, local-storage

I am wanting to store the results of a counter and return the info on another page.

so far I have this..

```
<script>

function clickCounter() {
document.getElementById("p4").style.display="none";

if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {

if (localStorage.clickcount) {
localStorage.clickcount=Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;}

else {
localStorage.clickcount=1;}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You have had " + localStorage.clickcount + " drink(s)";}

else {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage.";}
}
</script>
```

So the counter works when I press the button, it increments by 1 each time.

I am not sure where I am meant to stick in the `.setItem("result")`; and then the `.getItem("result")` methods.

Kinda clueless, any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the setItem() and getItem() methods to access localStorage rather than getting/setting properties directly against the "localStorage" object.  Here is an example of what I mean:

```
//Saving a new item named "foo" with a value of "bar"
window.sessionStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");

//Retrieveing a saved item:
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("foo");    //returns "bar"

//Deleting an item
localStorage.removeItem("foo");

//Clearing all local storage
localStorage.clear();
```

Here is a sample page I created that demonstrates how to add, remove and clear items from localstorage:

http://blackberry.github.com/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/html5/storage.html